# Ubuntu 18.04, terminal has no option to use tabs

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, tabs

From everything I've read, I SHOULD have an option under preferences to open new terminals in Tabs, and ctrl-alt-t should open a new tab, not a new terminal - but I'm missing that option :(

When I check my gnome-terminal version, it's coming up as 3.28.2, and I thought tabs were introduced back around version 3.10(ish).

Any suggestions? Can I reinstall my terminal or something? I learned (eons ago) on a large Unix system back in college, but it's been a lot of years on windows, and I'm just finally coming back, so I'm rusty at all of the things right now :P

Comment: Not familiar with gnome specifically but have you considered using `screen` instead, which is a console-based way to use tabs.  https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl+Shift+T`?

Comment: Yup, ctrl-shift-t just opens a new terminal window :(

Comment: **Voting to close** because `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`T` works for everyone else in the world and the problem hasn't been reported in five years by anyone else that I've noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and reinstalled the Ubuntu from scratch, and the terminal (including tabs) behaves the way I'd expect. Technology, eh?

Answer (score 0):

To add a new tab while in the terminal, click on File and select "New Tab".

Answer (score 0):

To open a new tab in your current terminal window select *File* -> *New Tab* or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

In order to be able to select *File* -> *New Tab* in your current terminal window make sure that the *Show menubar by default in new terminals* option is enabled in the terminal preferences in *Edit* (in menubar) or *Terminal ▼* (in Panel) -> *Preferences* -> *General* -> check the checkbox to the left of *Show menubar by default in new terminals*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

This will work if you have 'Enabled Shortcuts' option located at Preferences --> shortcuts checked ON.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I was in full screen mode. Right click to see the option to exit full screen.